# Unable to access pseudo elements in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, pseudo-element

Unable to select or access to the property of :before & :after element on Edge`s inspect element is there any thing we can do for that?

```css
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #d43959;
    border: 4px solid #ac1f3c;
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(213, 55, 55, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #d53737;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(245, 88, 99, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #f55863;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left: -26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/miqureshi/pen/KvRbLr)

This snippet working fine but on Microsoft edge I can't access this pseudo element:

```
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before
```

Comment: Note, it should be `::before`, with 2 colons

Comment: https://codepen.io/miqureshi/pen/KvRbLr

Message box has a top arrow which is being created by :after & :after by css. If you open this link on edge you can not see pseudo element.

Comment: @LGSon
please do consider as I shared link earlier.

Comment: Code samples should be within the question, both as code and/or code snippet, and if an external resource as Codepen or Fiddle is used, the essential part of the code needs to be in the question itself, or else it is of little use for future users. If you edit the question accordingly, I will remove my down vote, and maybe upvote instead

Comment: Improvements to inspecting pseudo-elements are available in the latest Windows Insider builds! https://insider.windows.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@supports` rule allows you to handle your pseudo element on Microsoft Edge.

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .selector {
        property: value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was previously not a feature supported in Edge, however as of version 16 (currently available in insider builds, and being released on October 17, 2017) this has been added.

Comment: I found this hack quite useful.
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) { .selector { property:value; } }

Comment: @miqureshi if the above comment is the solution to your own question, then post it as answer and mark it accepted!